# remove http response headers in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-headers

I have a problem with an app in Zend Framework (1).

In a specific action I try to remove some headers but in response I still recieve those headers:

```
    $this->getResponse->clearAllHeaders()
                      ->clearRawHeaders();
    $this->getResponse->setHeader('A-Header', 'headervalue');
```

I expect the response to be:

```
    HTTP/1.1 XXX Some HTTP status code
    A-Header: headervalue
```

but it is:

```
   HTTP/1.1 XXX Some HTTP status code
   Date: Sun, 14 Apr 2013 16:26:59 GMT
   Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze15
   Vary: Accept-Encoding
   Content-Length: 0
   Content-Type: text/html
```

How can I delete Date, Server, X-Powered-By, Vary, Content-Lenght, Content-Type? At least the Content* headers.

Thank you

Comment: In which part of the application do you clear them?

Comment: Hi zavg. I tried to do this in several points - did that in a specific action, in postDispatch hook, in dispatchLoopShutdown hook. But without success...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Apart from X-Powered-By, those headers each serve a purpose.

Comment: Hello Tim Fountain. I implement an authorization framework and the specs states that only several headers must be present. So I did not undersand well if I must strip out other headers... so in doubt I asked. BTW if there is a method (zned provides it) to remove a header... why I cannot remove it? At least the method should return some error code... nothing!
Thank you! closing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those headers are appended by Apache.

You can use `mod_headers` to control its behavior though:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html

Example:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Server
  Header unset X-Powered-By
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You're gonna need `mod_mime` and use the `RemoveType` directive. but i'm not sure it will let you strip off the Date and Content-Length as those are required by HTTP standards.

Comment: Also make sure you use `ServerSignature Off` and `SeverTokens Prod`.

Comment: Thank you. Did what you said and only `X-Powered-By` is stripped off. Also putting `ServerSignature Off` and `ServerTokens Prod` gave me the header Server: Apache. Without specifying what version it is.